# Highcharts Stacked Column Doesn't Combine Similar Datasets

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I'm trying to use the Highcharts Stack Column chart to display a grouping of different datasets per day but Highcharts doesn't seem to be grouping them correctly and displays each as a tick on a bar rather than combining similar groups.

**Current Behavior**

[image]

**Desired Behavior** *roughly: diff data here*

[image]

Here is a look at how the graph receives the data for one dataset. There are multiple ones tho they all look the same as this one. What I'd like to see is that if the milliseconds since Epoch matches, Highcharts combines these into a single bar on that particular date rather than the individual ticks it is creating as the screenshot above shows. Each array in the `data` array represents [timeSinceEpoch in milliseconds, countImTracking] which from what I've read in the docs is the correct shape of the data.

Thank you for your help!

```
"series": [
    {
        "name": "Test Data",
        "color": "#FBD362",
        "data": [
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ],
        [
            1518739200000,
            1
        ], 
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you please post the rest of your chart code?

Comment: If you just want to get the total counts for a given discreet time you could pre-process your data to sum it up. Then plot this result.

Comment: I moved your data to jsfiddle and everything looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b2md033e/ Please provide a live demo that illustrates the problem.